# How do I enable programers dvorak?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, dvorak

How do I enable programers dvorak?

I tried -

```
user@host:~$ setxkbmap -v 10 -layout us -variant dvp -option compose:102 -option numpad:shift3 -option kpdl:semi -option keypad:atm -option caps:shift

Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to load rules file ./rules/base...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base...
Success.
Applied rules from base:
rules:      base
model:      macintosh
layout:     us
variant:    dvp
options:    compose:102,numpad:shift3,kpdl:semi,keypad:atm,caps:shift
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   macintosh+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete+numpad(mac)+caps(shift)+numpad(shift3)
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+macintosh_vndr/us(dvp)+inet(apple)+compose(102)+keypad(ops)+keypad(hex)+keypad(atm)+kpdl(semi)
geometry:   macintosh(macintosh)
Error loading new keyboard description
```

and got errors. The same command seems to work fine for a lot of people.

I tried to see if I have `pdv` installed and got this -

```
user@host:~$ grep dvp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/*
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/digital_vndr: Is a directory
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dvp:xkb_symbols "dvp" {
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fujitsu_vndr: Is a directory
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/hp_vndr: Is a directory
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/macintosh_vndr: Is a directory
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/nec_vndr: Is a directory
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/nokia_vndr: Is a directory
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl://   pl(dvp_altquotes)).
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl:// Those rules overwrite only the following rules from us(dvp):
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl:xkb_symbols "dvp" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl:    include "us(dvp)"
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sgi_vndr: Is a directory
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sharp_vndr: Is a directory
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sony_vndr: Is a directory
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sun_vndr: Is a directory
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us:xkb_symbols "dvp" {
grep: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/xfree68_vndr: Is a directory
```

Any helps and tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to run that command with `sudo`? It could that it is trying to save it under `/etc/...` which requires root permissions.

Comment: Yes. Did not work :-(